# Do I need to train a separate DeepFake model for every input person?

Tags: python, deep-learning, autoencoder, gan

I would like to create a deep fake model of a specific person (we will call him Steve). I would then like to be able to upload a video of any random person and swap their face with Steve's.

So far I have seen most deep fake systems require datasets of person A and B. Is there a way to only train on person B and have a general version of A so that I can allow anyone to be the input?

Comment: "Is there a way to only train on person B and have a general version of A so that I can allow anyone to be the input? " -> probably not if you expect a realistic result. Also there are serious ethical issues with that... just saying.

Comment: thanks - for this use the target person would have full knowledge and granted permission

Answer (score 0):

The best results you will get if you train [both autoencoders on a specific person](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml-blog/deepfakes).

You can probably also use other pictures for the first autoencoder to make it usable for other person but the results won't be too good.